# Can I use aptitude instead of apt-get without problems?

Tags: apt, aptitude, package-management

I would like to use aptitude since its parameters are more consistent.

You can install it with: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Are there any reasons not to use it with elementary OS?

Comment: I can't find the source, but I remember having read that `apt-get` is considered the future standard on Ubuntu and eOS and thus the recommended option to choose.

Comment: @orschiro Aptitude and apt-get have evolved partly independently, and which one is the most advanced has varied over time. Currently aptitude suffers from a lack of maintenance (the historical maintainer no longer has enough time) so it's lagging behind apt-get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Yes you can.

#### Full answer:

What are the differences?

> 1. `aptitude` adds explicit per-package flags, indicating whether a package was automatically installed to satisfy a dependency: you can manipulate those flags (`aptitude markauto` or `aptitude unmarkauto`) to change the way aptitude treats the package.
>
>    `apt-get` keeps track of the same information, but will not show it explicitly. `apt-mark` can be used for manipulating the flags.
> 2. `aptitude` will offer to remove unused packages each time you remove an installed package, whereas apt-get will only do that if explicitly asked to with `apt-get autoremove` or specify `--auto-remove`.
> 3. `aptitude` acts as a single command-line front-end to most of the   functionalities in both `apt-get` and `apt-cache`.
> 4. In contrast to `apt-cache`'s "search", aptitude's "search" output also shows the installed/removed/purged status of a package (plus aptitude's own status flags).  Also, the "install" output marks which packages are being installed to satisfy a dependency, and which are being removed because unused.

[Source, Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1749/186134)

So there are a few differences between `apt-get` and `aptitude`. Because of this, it is recommended to chose one and stick with it. I've always used apt-get - partly because that's what the internet uses.

> `aptitude` is supposed to be a user level program whereas `apt-get` is supposed to be *used by* higher level programs like `aptitude`. It just turns out `apt-get` is easy to use by users so they just use it instead of using the higher level managers like `aptitude` and `synaptic`.

[Source, Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/347904/186134)

Why is it easier? I'd say because it doesn't do as much. It's like the difference between a clean UI and a cluttered UI:

[image]
[image]

New users are much more likely to want to use this UI ▲ because it's easier to understand and navigate.

The command line is scary enough when you come from Windows or OS X - the lack of being able to download everything by clicking (which you can (other than `ppa`s), but oh so slow) is worrying to a new user.

So anything that makes that experience better is going to make them happier.

> `apt-get` does have the advantage of being more memory-efficient. This is unlikely to be noticeable for most users; I wasn't really aware of it until I tried to upgrade packages on a full Debian install with 32MB of RAM.

[Source, Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use#comment161204_113994)

Currently, Ubuntu ships with `apt-get`, and `aptitude` avaliable to install. Popularity for `aptitude` (red has always been lower than `apt` (blue):

[image]

But this graph for `aptitude` vs `apt-get` suggests something else:

[image]

Probably just users are getting lazier and not typing `-get`.

Anyway, back to your question: "*Are there any reasons not to use it with elementary OS?*"

Not really - pick one and go with it. `apt-get` is the future standard, but as long as `aptitude` is avaliable why not use it?

Finally, one more article:

> Canonical has announced plans to switch all versions of Ubuntu to its new Snappy package manager. The new tool offers the promise of greater stability and security for the system and applications.
>
> Currently, Ubuntu uses the Advanced Packaging Tool (`apt`) and the lower-level `dpkg` tool to manage packages. They are inherited from Debian and are used on a wide range of distros, including Elementary OS.

[Source](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-stable-future-ubuntu)

[image]

[Image Source](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/snappy)

Comment: very good answer! "whereas apt-get is supposed to be used by higher level programs like aptitude" aren't apt-get and aptitude both frontends for apt? for me aptitude is easyer because it is one programm to use like apti + [TAB] and it has multiple options for dependency resolution.

Comment: Why do you recommend to pick one and stick with it? There's no technical problem with mixing them up. The only reason I can think of to pick one is to have less to learn, but it's definitely fine to use apt-get for its quicker command line and aptitude for its interactive interface.

Comment: @Tim `apt-get` has also supported these flags for far longer than elementary has existed, so they aren't an issue.

Comment: Tim, you **MUST** give [proper attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) when you quote somebody else's words. That includes both marking up the text as a quote (which you did) and including the person's identification (for Stack Exchange, a link to their profile), which you failed to do. If you don't want to acknowledge the author, write the text in your own words.

Comment: I have little experience with `aptitude` but on one occasion I was very impressed by it, as it was the way to [solving a very tricky problem when Wine couldn't be installed](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/352/170). Has `apt-get` such detailed options as the one used there (`sudo aptitude --full-resolver -f install <packagename>`)?

Comment: @cipricus No, there are problems that only aptitude can solve.